# Spring & Reactor: Subscribe to a binary function of two arguments with Flux from repo

Tags: spring, binary, flux, subscribe, reactor

Suppose I have a binary function with the following definition:

```
Mono<ObjectA> someBinaryFunction(String someString, enum someEnum)
```

And I want to use a flux from a Spring repo to subscribe to this function after some operations:

```
    repo.findAll()
            .filter( item -> itemField < someValue)
            .flatMapSequential( item ->
              Flux.just(item.getValue1(), enum.ENUMVALUE)
              ).subscribe(baseClass::someBinaryFunction)
```

How can this be achieved, and what is the best practice for subscribing to a function with N arguments using Flux? My first intuition was to use sequentialFlatMap as above but this failed.

Answer (score 0):

If the original intention was to convert Flux of items to flux of pairs like (item, enumVal), the solution could be as follows:

```
repo.findAll()
        .filter( item -> itemField < someValue)
        .flatMapSequential( item ->
          Flux.just(Tuples.of(item.getValue1(), enum.ENUMVALUE))
          ).subscribe(tuple->baseClass.someBinaryFunction(tuple.getT1(), tuple.getT2()))
```

The **Tuples.of(...)** method creates the pair of type **Tuple2<ItemType, EnumType>** and then **tuple.getT1()** and **tuple.getT2()** extract the 1st and 2nd members of this pair for following usage as *someBinaryFunction()* parameters.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, adding an additional explaination might help the OP and future readers.